# max Absolute difference using CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

We have the following  serial C code operating on

two vectors a[] and b[]:

```
double a[20000],b[20000],r=0.9;

for(int i=1;i<=10000;++i)
{
    a[i]=r*a[i]+(1-r)*b[i]];
    errors=max(errors,fabs(a[i]-b[i]);
    b[i]=a[i];
}
```

Please tell us on how to port this code to CUDA and cublas?

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to implement this reduction in Thrust using `thrust::transform_reduce`. This solution fuses the entire operation, as talonmies suggests:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

// this functor unpacks a tuple and then computes
// a weighted absolute difference of its members
struct weighted_absolute_difference
{
  double r;

  weighted_absolute_difference(const double r)
    : r(r)
  {}

  __host__ __device__
  double operator()(thrust::tuple<double,double> t)
  {
    double a = thrust::get<0>(t);
    double b = thrust::get<1>(t);

    a = r * a + (1.0 - r) * b;

    return fabs(a - b);
  }
};

int main()
{
  using namespace thrust;

  const std::size_t n = 20000;

  const double r = 0.9;

  device_vector<double> a(n), b(n);

  // initialize a & b
  ...

  // do the reduction
  double result =
    transform_reduce(make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(a.begin(), b.begin())),
                     make_zip_iterator(make_tuple(a.end(),   b.end())),
                     weighted_absolute_difference(r),
                     -1.f,
                     maximum<double>());

  // note that this solution does not set
  // a[i] = r * a[i] + (1 - r) * b[i]

  return 0;
}
```

Note that we do not perform the assignment `a[i] = r * a[i] + (1 - r) * b[i]` in this solution, though it would be simple to do so after the reduction using `thrust::transform`. It is not safe to modify `transform_reduce`'s arguments in either functor.

Comment: Nice solution, just need to fix a.end() appearing twice where the second one should be b.end() and to mention that the result is the return value of transform_reduce.

Answer (score 0):

This second line in your loop:

```
errors=max(errors,fabs(a[i]-b[i]);
```

is known as a *reduction*. Fortunately there is reduction example code in the CUDA SDK - take a look at this and use it as a template for your algorithm.

You probably want to split this into two separate operations (possibly as two separate kernels) - one for the parallel part (calculation of `bp[]` values) and a second for the reduction (calculate `errors`).

Comment: Why would this need to be done using two operations? The computation and the reduction can be safely fused -- the whole thing is embarassingly parallel.

Comment: @talonmies: since the OP is evidently a CUDA noob I felt that it would be easier to use the reduction example from the CUDA SDK to do the reduction for `errors` and then they would just need a simple operation for the straightforward parallel part prior to the reduction. Not necessarily two kernels, although it would probably make it easier to debug.